# Why doesn't current exit an appliance through the earth wire?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Any appliance with a metal body has three pins, the thickest and longest one leading to the earth conductor because of it's low resistance. In that case, why doesn't the current exit through the earth wire which is a better conductor than the neutral wire?

Comment: Because in normal use there should be no way for current to get to the earth (ground) wire. If there is a fault such the case of the device is not hot, then the earth wire is there to make sure that you don't end up dead in a heap on the floor. The fact that it is 'longest' only ensures that it makes contact to the outlet first, establishing the safety ground before hot/neutral engage in the socket.

Comment: @Jon Custer "Because in normal use there should be no way for current to get to the earth (ground) wire." Can you elaborate please?

Comment: One standard use case is a power tool with a metal case. The ground wire is connected to the case. The case is insulated from the actual working bits, including whatever the hot and neutral are connected to. In normal use, the case should never see hot or neutral. Should something break and a wire that is hot contacts the case, the ground wire is there to short it to ground rather than letting you be the path to ground. Ground is connected to neutral only at the panel. No current in normal use should go through ground, only hot and neutral.

Comment: @JonCuster, that should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Can you explain why you believe the ground wire and the neutral wire to have different resistances? They should both be so low resistance as to effectively have no difference in resistance.

Answer (score 1):

One standard use case is a power tool with a metal case. The ground wire is connected to the case. The case is insulated from the actual working bits, including whatever the hot and neutral are connected to. In normal use, the case should never see hot or neutral. Should something break and a wire that is hot contacts the case, the ground wire is there to short it to ground rather than letting you be the path to ground. Ground is connected to neutral only at the panel. No current in normal use should go through ground, only hot and neutral.

Note that nowadays you generally do not find metal-cased power tools (they were quite common in the 1970's for example). Now they are generally 'double insulated' with an insulating outer cover, preventing you from being shocked. Many of those tools do not need to have a 3-prong (hot/neutral/ground) plug because of their design. This would, generally, be determined from the UL (or other Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory) process And, of course, many tools are now battery powered, and anything below 50V is considered intrinsically safe (but under certain circumstances can still kill you).

Check your local electrical codes. For the US, those are derived from NFPA 70 (standard power stuff like your house) and NFPA 70E (laboratory).

Comment: So basically, the earth wire is insulated from the hot and neutral ones, but not from the metallic appliance. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The earth wire in any electrical appliance is connected to its outer metallic body. In the appliance the body is insulated from the rest by suitable means of the inside circuit so that the user may not receive an electric shock. Now if there is any fault in the insulation due to any reason the current enters in the metallic body of the appliance so now the current will flow to the earth wire.
Note that The earth wire is not directly connected to the circuit it is a precautionary safety measure so that any leakage of the current in the metallic body of the appliance doesn't cause any harm to the user.
As soon as the current leaks into the metallic body it continuously flows to the earth which results in a kind of short circuit . So the fuse blows off and the user is protected.

Comment: So, the earth wire is insulated from the phase and neutral ones, but not from the metallic body of the appliance? And, how does the fuse, that is connected to the phase, blow off?